# Not able to run tests on gitlab CI using headless browser anymore

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

I am getting the following error while running my test automation scripts on linux (gitlab CI-CD): 'The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.'

The docker image I am using is : image: markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-11

It was working fine till chromedriver version 114. But it has started giving this error now. I have tried all the versions from 115 to current 120.

I am now not sure if this is a webdriver issue or the chrome browser issue. Please help

I have tried all the chromedriver versions for linux above the version 114 which I was using previously. I also have added 'mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm' in my pipeline as I was previously facing memory issues.

Comment: Update: I am using browser in headless mode only